# Link Event with Date to Event with Date in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am having Difficulty with the following challenge i am facing.
For some reason i am unable;e to make this work as i do not now how to pull the data out as required.

I have the following Table:

```
Device ID event_id  TransDate           SeqNo       DriverId    Company Fleet_Code  FirstName     LastName  Employee_no ID_Tag 
433 110 14/07/2014 09:20    1695125191  Comp001 Test    Test    Pieter  A   Comp001     16A65C2C 
433 110 14/07/2014 10:04    1695160943  Comp001 Test    Test    Pieter  A   Comp001 16A65C2C 
433 111 14/07/2014 10:04    1695161098  Comp001 Test    Test    Pieter  A   Comp001 16A65C2C 
433 110 14/07/2014 11:00    1695206788  Comp002 Test    Test    Cornel  B   Comp002 16A5F51E 
433 111 14/07/2014 11:00    1695207085  Comp002 Test    Test    Cornel  B   Comp002 16A5F51E 
433 110 14/07/2014 12:27    1695281449  Comp004 Test    Test    Monique C   Comp004 16A63878 
433 110 14/07/2014 12:27    1695281510  Comp005 Test    Test    Laura   D   Comp005 16A6C788 
433 111 14/07/2014 12:27    1695281635  Comp005 Test    Test    Laura   D   Comp005 16A6C788 
433 111 14/07/2014 12:27    1695281705  Comp004 Test    Test    Monique C   Comp004 16A63878 
433 110 14/07/2014 13:24    1695329075  Comp003 Test    Test    Bonita  E   Comp003 16A62969 
433 110 14/07/2014 13:24    1695329133  Comp001 Test    Test    Pieter  A   Comp001 16A65C2C 
433 111 14/07/2014 13:25    1695329526  Comp003 Test    Test    Bonita  E   Comp003 16A62969 
433 111 14/07/2014 13:25    1695329582  Comp001 Test    Test    Pieter  A   Comp001 16A65C2C
```

I am trying to get the following result:

```
event_id DateTime           event_id DateTime 
110      14/07/2014 09:20   111      14/07/2014 10:04 
110      14/07/2014 10:04   111      14/07/2014 10:04 
110      14/07/2014 11:00   111      14/07/2014 11:00 
110      14/07/2014 12:27   111      14/07/2014 12:27 
110      14/07/2014 12:27   111      14/07/2014 12:27 
110      14/07/2014 13:24   111      14/07/2014 13:25 
110      14/07/2014 13:24   111      14/07/2014 13:25
```

I want to extract the events 110 with its date time and then next to it the event 111 with its date time, almost like you will do with a clock in and out situation.

i have tried a couple of sites but some of them require two tables i am limited on space a i have very large tables and am trying to make this work from a View.

any help or link to something similar will be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want the next event of type 111 after each 110.  Here is a way using a correlated subquery:

```
select event_id, datetime, 111 as event_id,
       (select top 1 datetime
        from table t2
        where t2.event_id = 111 and
              t2.datetime > t.datetime
        order by t2.datetime
       ) as datetime
from table t
where event_id = 110;
```